# Performance impact on base type to custom type conversion

Tags: go, types, casting

does type conversion from base to custom (or custom to base) has negative impacts on performance?

Simple and common scenario.

I have a **package B** where, for merely syntax reason, I've used some custom types  like:

```
package B

type MyStringType string
type MyInt64Type int64
type MyIntType int64


var StringVar MyStringType
var Int64Var MyInt64Type 
var IntVar MyIntType

StringVar = "hello"
Int64Var = 10
IntVar = 20
```

Now, I have to use data from **package B** in my **package A**, where I need to compare variables but with type conversion (obviously):

```
package A

import "project/B"

var string_var string
var int64_var int64
var int_var int

string_var = "hi"
int64_var = 100
int_var = 1000


//base to custom

if B.MyStringType(string_var) == B.StringVar {
    fmt.Println("Equal")
}

if B.MyInt64Type(int64_var) == B.Int64Var {
    fmt.Println("Equal")
}

if B.MyIntType(int_var) == B.IntVar{
    fmt.Println("Equal")
}



//custom to base

if string(B.StringVar) == string_var {
    fmt.Println("Equal")
}

if int64(B.Int64Var) == int64_var {
    fmt.Println("Equal")
}

if int(B.IntVar) == int_var {
    fmt.Println("Equal")
}
```

Question: when used massively, like in a thousands of iterations, this type conversion has some performance impact?

Thanks

Comment: You can answer this type of questions pretty easily by benchmarking which is a nice way to learn things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no runtime impact when converting between names for the same type. This is entirely a compile-time feature and produces no additional instructions at runtime.